# Yii (re)render scripts after rendering an iframe

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

Using Yii 1.1.14 on Apache 2.2 with PHP 5.3.10

The default entry point into a controller renders a layout with a sidebar that contains an autocomplete widget and a $content section.  The autocomplete widget is a rip (see [blog](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/217/custom-autocomplete-display-and-value-submission/)) and inside the **run** method the JQuery autocomplete is method chained to adjust how results are displayed.

There is an action on the controller that renders a view that has an iframe (with an href to another site).  When that view is rendered the JavaScript registered by the autocomplete extension is gone.  Traced the output of the render call and it is not present.  However, the script is still registered.

Tried to override the `afterRender` method and when the view in question was rendered do something like:

```
 Yii::app()->getClientScript()-render(&$output);
```

which does append the Javascript.  Unfortunately, the Javascript is still missing.

Put a trace at the beginning and the end of the widget's **run** method.  Seeing a trace when the normal entry point is rendered as well when the view with the iframe is rendered.  So the widget is getting run correctly.

Could it be that the action that causes the view with the iframe isn't terminating correctly?  Or do embedding iframe just blow out Javascript and there is no fix?

Comment: Just looked at the Yii CController code.  What is the first line?  A call to the getClientScript()->render($output) just like I was trying in the `afterRender`.  Okej, now I am stumped.

Comment: If the iframe tag is removed from the view then the JavaScript is rendered.  So the iframe is the problem.

Comment: Could move the registered script up to the header BUT Yii puts the jquery-ui after the body.

Comment: Overriding the CWidget's `registerScriptFile` method let's me put jquery-ui in the header but still need to add my script in the body just after the autocomplete widget is rendered.

Comment: Got a workaround.  Overwritten CWidget's `registerScriptFile` and set my script to POS_HEAD then wrapped it in a jquery on load event handler (`$onLoad = "jQuery(window).on('load',function() {\n".$js."\n});";`).